# how to draw mesh gradient in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui, mobile-development

can you please explain how to draw/make a mesh gradient in swiftUI similar to the attached image?
I it straightforward to use LinearGradient, RadialGradient, or Angular gradient but none of them produce something similar to the attached image as far as I know.
Can you please help me with my request?

[image]

I tried different values for the the angle degree, but still not the result I'm looking for. Below is the code I have so far:

```
struct ContentView: View {
let gradient = Gradient(colors: [Color(.systemRed),
                                 Color(.systemBlue),
                                 Color(.systemGray),
                                 Color(.systemPurple),
                                 Color(.systemYellow),
                                 Color(.systemRed)])

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Text("")
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    .background(
        AngularGradient(gradient: gradient,
                        center: .center,
                        angle: .degrees(180)) // (180 + 45)
    )
 }
```

Comment: please post the code you tried.

Comment: I added the code I have so far, thank you for your comment

Comment: Did you try `LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 1), endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1, y: 0))`? seems giving a similar to what you want

Comment: I have not, I will try it and share the result shortly

Comment: I tried it and it did not produce the same result I'm looking for, but appreciate your help

Comment: truthfully the image you shared is more complex than just gradient. So if you have an algorithm for it, you could recreate it using several shapes for example (arranged together with no gaps). But if you do not have an algorithm, then it's not that easy to reproduce

Comment: that explains why I've been having a hard time to reproduce it. Thanks a lot though for your help.